# Persistence context scope in a ejb j2ee and other questions

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb-3.0

My apologies for lengthy question.

I'm working on a EJB application. I have two EJB eclipse projects(`Ejb1` and `Ejb2`) and other dynamic web application(`Web1`) which  will be compiled and added to a parent `EjbEar` project and packaged as `EjbEar.ear` file.

**Question1:** I've first created a `persistence.xml` in `EJb1` project's `META-INF` folder and this helps me inject the entitymanager into the session beans and start working. (code below)

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "ejbPersistanceunit")
private EntityManager em;
```

In `Ejb2` I've created another session bean and injected the entitymanager same like above(here I `did not` configure the persistence.xml) but when I invoke from the client, I get the response from both the Ejb1 and Ejb2 projects.

Why does the EntityManger get shared between two ejbprojects? If my Ejb2 project needs another persistence.xml for a different data source, do I create another one or have it included in the existing persistence.xml? will it also be shared ? Does my `Web1` project also get hold of the Entitymanager in the same way?

**Question2:** I have sessionbeans in `Ejb1` project and their remote interfaces are created  in `Web1` project but what is the best approach in exposing these newly created Entities/Interfaces in an ejb project? (For more than one Ejb project in an Enterprise application)

**Question3:** Ejb 3.0 no longer have the home and remote interfaces correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the EntityManger get shared between two ejbprojects?

You can disable this sharing by isoloting Ejb jars if you don't want. If jboss open `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` and setting the property `ear-subdeployments-isolated` to true

> If my Ejb2 project needs another persistence.xml for a different data
>   source, do I create another one or have it included in the existing
>   persistence.xml? will it also be shared ?

It purely depends on your use case,
if you have multiple datasources in your system then I would define my persistence.xml based 
the way I package my beans accessing the Persistence Unit.

In case, if all of the entities belonging to both of the datasources are packaged together then I would define 2 persistence Unit in the same `persistence.xml`
if they are packaged in differently in 2 jars, then any of the following is a possibility

1. if beans accessing the entities serviced by the same
   persistenceUnit/Datasource are packaged together then I would create
   2 persistence.xml with associated `PersistenceUnit` in 2 jars
2. if isolation is set to false, then I can define my `persistence.xml` like
   above or I would define 2 `persistenceUnit` together in a single
   `persistence.xml` and would make sure that the jar with
   `Persistence.xml` is deployed first

> Does my Web1 project also get hold of the Entitymanager in the same
>   way?

Yes, you can get access to persistenceContext

**Note:** I assumed your app server to be JBoss

> I have sessionbeans in Ejb1 project and their remote interfaces are
>   created in Web1 project but what is the best approach in exposing
>   these newly created Entities/Interfaces in an ejb project? (For more
>   than one Ejb project in an Enterprise application)

As far as my knowledge goes, it depends on your system Architecture/ Design. If I were you, I would have packaged my remote interfaces and Beans together in the same EJB-Jar and I would either use Business Delegate that lookup the EJB beans or as Remote interfaces are visible in the web, I would inject the same in the web layer and use it.

> Ejb 3.0 no longer have the home and remote interfaces correct?

There are no interface called home & remote but the concept is still there in the form of annotations `@Remote & @Local`, which means you define your interfaces and you can declare either `@Remote or @Local` either at the interface level or at the Bean level.